# Save all Outlook mailitems to disk with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have some experience with VBA in Excel, but taking my first steps in Outlook. I need to save all e-mail messages in a designated Outlook folder (`Inbox\input`) to disk (`D:\myArchive\Email\`) as .msg files and move mail item to archive folder in Outlook (`Inbox\archive`).

I have set up a mail rule in Outlook that moves mail to archive folder and runs a script below which actually does what I need. The problem is that I get mail rule error pop-ups occasionally and I struggle to track down the reason. Hence looking to turn away from Outlook mail rule and cycle through all folder contents "on-demand".

How could I convert it to cycle through Outlook folder as  well as displace the mail item? Currently running Outlook 2019. Thanks!

edit: sorry, late clarification - target folder is in another mailbox (Office 365 shared mailbox). How to target a different account?

```
Public Sub saveEmailtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim saveFolder, msgName1, msgName2 As String
    
    saveFolder = "D:\myArchive\Email\"
    
    msgName1 = Replace(itm.Subject, ":", "")
    msgName2 = Replace(msgName1, "/", "_")
    
    itm.SaveAs saveFolder & msgName2 & ".msg", olMSG
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code assumes that both the `input` and `archive` folders are located within the default inbox.

```
Public Sub saveAndArchiveInputEmails()

    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "D:\myArchive\Email\"
    
    Dim sourceFolder As Folder
    Dim destFolder As Folder
    With Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Set sourceFolder = .Folders("input")
        Set destFolder = .Folders("archive")
    End With

    Dim itm As Object
    Dim i As Long
    With sourceFolder
        For i = .Items.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set itm = .Items(i)
            If TypeName(itm) = "MailItem" Then
                saveEmailtoDisk saveFolder, itm
                itm.Move destFolder
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub

Public Sub saveEmailtoDisk(ByRef saveFolder As String, ByVal itm As Object)
    
    Dim msgName1, msgName2 As String
    
    msgName1 = Replace(itm.Subject, ":", "")
    msgName2 = Replace(msgName1, "/", "_")
    
    itm.SaveAs saveFolder & msgName2 & ".msg", olMSG
    
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

For a shared mailbox, try the following instead...

```
With Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim sharedEmail As Recipient
    Set sharedEmail = .CreateRecipient("someone@abc.com")
    
    Dim sourceFolder As Folder
    Set sourceFolder = .GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedEmail, olFolderInbox).Folders("input")
    
    Dim destFolder As Folder
    Set destFolder = .GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedEmail, olFolderInbox).Folders("archive")
    

End With
```

For your default inbox...

```
Dim myInbox As Folder
Set myInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

Comment: When moving or deleting use a reverse loop. For Each is a forward counting loop.

Comment: @niton Thanks for catching that, I'll amend my post accordingly.

Comment: I have amended my post.

Comment: @Domenic sorry for not clarifying this - in fact target folder is NOT in my default mailbox - it's a shared mailbox within Office365 (not set up as a separate account in Outlook). How could I address a different mailbox?

Also, I couldn't figure out how to target default mailbox inbox itself. Working within subfolders of the inbox itself works fine!